# How does Sublime Text 3 know function definitions?

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3it ships a feature called "Goto Definition", which I think is mostly based on the highlight rules, but how is it working in details?

Comment: Through the use of `Symbol List.tmPreferences` as seen e.g. [here](https://github.com/kodLite/cppStartingKit/blob/master/Symbol%20List%20Hide%20Forward%20Decls.tmPreferences).

Comment: @Rapptz Any introductions or comments here?